# Analyzing a Manova

Tags: manova, ecology

I've tried to do a MANOVA analysis of a dataset, to control the distribution of multiple species to three variables (FISH, EROSIONFORCE and ZONATION). To do so I used the mvabund package in R.

[image: Dataset]

The summary function of lm in mvabund yield

[image: Outcome]

Have I managed to do an MANOVA here, since all species are listed in the calculation outcome? I was expecting the FISH variable to be most significant, so it seems right, I just need a second opinion.